# Mount azure drive for read

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I create a WCF service to upload files to an azure drive, How can i read the drive files from other web role without mount a snapshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a snapshot of the page blob containing the Azure Drive, then mount the snapshot as read-only. The snapshot function is near-instantaneous.

Here's the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.clouddrive.snapshot.aspx) that shows a full example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/04/16/using-smb-to-share-a-windows-azure-drive-among-multiple-role-instances.aspx

Comment: i have seen this,but with this can i use the disk from another hosted service in azure?

Comment: Yes, it will be read only, but that is what it is intended to do.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS APPROACH. I tried for months, the problem is the shares using bandwidth on both sides, ALL-THE-TIME. Better just create snapshot and mount, it will create local cache for MUCH MUCH MUCH better performance